# xcodebuild fails in Xcode version 7.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

We recently upgraded Xcode to version 7.3. 
Since then the xcodebuild command fails when executing the test action on device.
Testing via the Xcode UI works with no issues

Heres the exception:

```
2016-03-28 08:27:24.129 xcodebuild[20029:9747786]  DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-10174/DVTFoundation/Utilities/DVTTask.m:252
Details:  The launch path must be set before launching.
Object:   <DVTiPhoneTask: 0x7fd96a67b8d0>
Method:   -launchRunningTerminationHandlerOnQueue:error:terminationHandler:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd969c53870>{number = 57, name = (null)}
Hints: None
```

This example DOES succeed:

```
xcodebuild -workspace `pwd`/iComposer.xcworkspace -scheme XXXXXXX -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,id=XXXXXXX' CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=`pwd`/Builds/
```

This one fails (note the 'test'):

```
xcodebuild -workspace `pwd`/iComposer.xcworkspace -scheme XXXXXXX -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,id=XXXXXXX' CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=`pwd`/Builds/ test
```

Comment: Did you have this same setup working on Xcode 7.2 or earlier? I've just encountered it for the first time. If it was working and then it stopped, that makes me suspect an Apple bug/regression.

Comment: Did you find the cause? I'm also getting the same assertion failure error in Jenkins builds